# Reading data from xml to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable

My xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Category>
  <Youth>

  </Youth>
  <GeneralStores>

  </GeneralStores>
  <Schools>

  </Schools>
  <Colleges>

  </Colleges>
  <GovernmentOffices>

  </GovernmentOffices>
  <Restaurants>

  </Restaurants>
  <MovieTheatres>

  </MovieTheatres>

</Category>
```

I need data table like

```
_______________________

Category
__________
Youth
GeneralStores
Schools
Colleges
GovernmentOffices
Restaurants
MovieTheatres
```

I am binding this datatable to telrik rad grid on need datasource event

here is my .cs code

```
protected void CategoriesRadGrid_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //create the DataTable that will hold the data
        DataTable CategoryDT = new DataTable("MainCategory");
        CategoryDT.Columns.Add("Category", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
      CategoryDT.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\MyID\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeName\InfoXML\XMLCategory.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

1. Code executes good with no data in data table.
2. Also tell me How to give file location when file is on servers?
   presently I am using my local machine path where the file is located.

Comment: please remember to upvote the answers that helped you.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote

Comment: Place a `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` in the `catch` block, and run this in the debugger. You're ignoring any exceptions!

Answer (score 2):

use XmlDocument to read your XML

```
XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("physical path to file.xml");
// doc.LoadXml(stringXml);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

if(doc.ChildNodes[1]!=null)
   dt.Columns.Add(doc.ChildNodes[1].Name); //Assuming you want the rood node to be the only column of the datatable

 //iterate through all the childnodes of your root i.e. Category
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes [1].ChildNodes )
{
  dt.Rows.Add(node.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private static DataTable BuildDataTable(XElement x)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(x.Name.ToString()));
            foreach (var d in x.Descendants())
            {
                DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
                drow[0] = d.Value;
                dt.Rows.Add(drow);
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

the method will iterate through the xml and create the dataTable. [`Xelement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) is part linq and will require .Net framework 4. It represents an XML element.

To call the method :

```
//this answers your second question, 
//use Server.MapPath to find your file.
XElement x = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(".") + @"\test.xml");

DataTable dt = BuildDataTable(x);
```